# PHP ftp_mdtm() not support by server?

Tags: php, ftp

Are there any other solutions but `ftp_mdtm()` for getting file modification date/time using FTP functions?

Answer (score 3):

The format of an FTP list output was not standardised for computer parsing, so if you want to support all possible FTP servers, you need to come up with your own parser.

But let's start with the easiest way: PHP supports an [FTP wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php). Since PHP 5.1 you can use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to fetch the modification file of a remote file by using `ftp://user:password@host/path/file` as argument.

You can also try to use [`curl_getinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) of the PHP cURL extension.

If that does not work because your FTP server is of AIX, VMS, EBCDIC or some other "exotic" nature, you can parse the directory listing manually.

First of all, if you are very lucky, the FTP server supports `MLST` or `MLSD` command. You can issue them using [`ftp_raw()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-raw.php) in PHP. The output is explained in [RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659#page-23). The date can easily be parsed and is returned in UTC.

If you are less lucky, you need to fall back to the legacy `LIST` command used by [`ftp_rawlist()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-rawlist.php). There is no standard on how the output looks like, so you need heuristics. FileZilla is very good at handling legacy FTP servers. If you really need a parser and have some time, simply port [FileZilla's directory listing parser](http://svn.filezilla-project.org/filezilla/FileZilla3/trunk/src/engine/directorylistingparser.cpp?view=markup) to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 5.1, you can just use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/filemtime) with a valid [`ftp://...`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php) file path.

Example:

```
$user = 'peter';
$password = 'secret123';
$mtime = filemtime("ftp://$user:$password@example.com/some_file.txt");
```